# How to do a "safe" SPLIT in Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The following code on Google BigQuery throws an index out of bounds error.

```
SELECT 
  SPLIT(CONCEPT_CKI, "!")[OFFSET(0)] AS Standard_Name
  ,SPLIT(CONCEPT_CKI, "!")[OFFSET(1)] AS Standard_Code

FROM 
(
      SELECT "MULTUM!123" AS CONCEPT_CKI
      UNION ALL
      SELECT "MULTUM234" AS CONCEPT_CKI

)
```

We would like the split to work on fields it can work on - and simply yield a NULL value for the second field when it cannot. (i.e. somewhat similar to how the SAFE_CAST command gives a NULL if it cannot do the cast.)

How do we do a "safe" SPLIT on fields in Google BigQuery?

Answer (score 7):

Use SAFE_OFFSET as in below example

```
SELECT 
  SPLIT(CONCEPT_CKI, "!")[OFFSET(0)] AS Standard_Name
  ,SPLIT(CONCEPT_CKI, "!")[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS Standard_Code

FROM 
(
      SELECT "MULTUM!123" AS CONCEPT_CKI
      UNION ALL
      SELECT "MULTUM234" AS CONCEPT_CKI

)
```

with output

```
Row Standard_Name   Standard_Code    
1   MULTUM          123  
2   MULTUM234       null
```

instead of `Array index 1 is out of bounds (overflow)` for original query

Comment: It is sort of ironic that the question itself contains its own answer.